# Console application does not accept input when a windows form is displayed

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, console

I have created a console application. I want to make the label (on the form) display whatever I type in the console, but the console hangs when I run the form.

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        Label a;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Form abc = new Form(); 
            Label a = new Label();
            a.Text = "nothing";
            abc.Controls.Add(a);
            Application.Run(abc);
            System.Threading.Thread t=new System.Threading.Thread(Program.lol);
            t.Start();


        }
        public static void lol()
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            p.a.Text = s;
            lol();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application.Run` will block until the form has closed. So you should call *that* on a separate thread.

However, your UI will then be executing on that separate thread - and you mustn't "touch" a UI element from a thread other than the UI thread, so after calling `Console.ReadLine()`, you'll need to use `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke` to make changes in the UI.

Additionally, you're currently declaring a *local variable* called `a`, but never assigning a value to `Program.a`.

Here's a complete version which works:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    private Program()
    {
        // Actual form is created in Start...
    }

    private void StartAndLoop()
    {
        Label label = new Label { Text = "Nothing" };
        Form form = new Form { Controls = { label } };
        new Thread(() => Application.Run(form)).Start();
        // TODO: We have a race condition here, as if we
        // read a line before the form has been fully realized,
        // we could have problems...

        while (true)
        {
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            Action updateText = () => label.Text = line;
            label.Invoke(updateText);
        }
   }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().StartAndLoop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems in your code, I won't include the naming choices.

- `Application.Run` is blocking. The rest of your code won't get called until your `Form` is closed.
- You're recursively calling `lol()`, and I wouldn't suggest it. Use a `while` loop instead.
- You're trying to set the text of a `Label` from a different thread than the one the control was created on. You will need to use `Invoke` or a similar method.

Here's a full example of how your code *could* be. I tried to modify as few things as possible.

```
class Program
{
    static Label a;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Thread(ExecuteForm);
        t.Start();
        lol();
    }

    static void lol()
    {
        var s = Console.ReadLine();
        a.Invoke(new Action(() => a.Text = s));
        lol();
    }

    public static void ExecuteForm()
    {
        var abc = new Form();
        a = new Label();
        a.Text = "nothing";
        abc.Controls.Add(a);
        Application.Run(abc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're spawning the form before you create the new `Thread`. This means your program never actually creates the new `Thread` until the the `Form` is exited.

You need to use

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(Program.lol);
t.Start();
Application.Run(abc);
```