# Call WinForm methods from thread where WinForm was started

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, browser

I searched and tried each of the answers I've already found, but I couldn't find this exact situation.

I have `Class1` that creates a form object and starts it with `Application.Run(Form1)`. Inside `Form1` is an encapsulated `WebBrowser` object I am using to navigate to web pages. `Class1` is being controlled by console commands. An example of what I'm trying to do is:

1. Application.Run(Form1) happens when the console app starts
2. I type loadpage1 in console, and a method in Form1 gets called that navigates the browser to web page #1
3. I type loadpage2 in console, and a different method in Form1 gets called that navigates to web page #2

Is this possible? I've already tried calling the methods directly but it seems that Application.Run() blocks the console app thread.

Thank you.

Comment: Well you could try `new Thread(() => Application.Run()).Start();` to not block the console app thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191314/console-application-does-not-accept-input-when-a-windows-form-is-displayed

Comment: @Mike Wow I didn't see that one, I'll check it out real quick

Comment: @Jashaszun I tried that a few minutes ago and it doesn't block anymore, but the method calls still aren't going through, so I'm checking out the link above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mike is right that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191314/console-application-does-not-accept-input-when-a-windows-form-is-displayed) is a good in-depth decription of this technique.  I just wanted to add, that, in your particular situation, you want to make sure whatever process is handling commands from the console as a reference to your form instance that has the web browser control in it.

So, something like

```
CustomForm f = //get reference to web browser form
f.Invoke(() => { //whatever you want to do on the form's thread };
```

Invoke() ensures that whatever is executed in the lambda expression is executed on the form/ control's thread.

Comment: Now my web browser antics can't login to the web page anymore, sigh. But this solution with some tweaking did what I wanted it to. I changed it to invoke a delegate I defined in the form. Works beautifully. Thanks.